# How to find out which stored procedure is using a specific table?

Tags: mysql

I have 100 stored procedures and some of those are using table_123. So how to find all stored procedures that are using this table?

I tried `SHOW PROCEDURE STATUS` but it is not giving me the right info that I want.

Comment: I assume `SP` stands for "Stored Procedure"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Untested by me but possibly

```
SELECT *
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
WHERE ROUTINE_DEFINITION LIKE '%table_123%'
```

At the risk of a few false positives.

Comment: @jack `ROUTINE_DEFINITION` then?